# Simplifying a regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I would like to simplify this regex (myExpr) :

```
\s+#[A-z][A-Za-z0-9-_]+|^\s*#[A-z][A-Za-z0-9-_]+
```

So I wrote this :

```
[\s+|^\s*](#[A-z][A-Za-z0-9-_]+)
```

To use it in

```
re.findall(myExpr,string)
```

The first regex worked but not the last. Is there any mistake I've made in the second one ?

Comment: `[\s+|^\s*]` is the character set matching whitespace, plus sign, pipe character, ...

Comment: Please post an example of the `subject string` and the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parenthesis `(…)` instead of brackets `[…]` as the latter denote a character class:

```
(\s+|^\s*)(#[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-_]+)
```

You could also use this as `a+` is equivalent to `aa*`:

```
(^|\s)\s*(#[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-_]+)
```

Comment: If Python supports it, you can use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (per definition of `\w`). I find myself wondering about the OP's `A-z` -- while valid, it could very well be a mistake.

Comment: @Jongware Oh, haven’t noticed the latter. In fact, this is a common mistake as the range  `A` (0x41) to `z` (0x7A) does not only contain `A`-`Z` (0x41-0x5A) and `a`-`z` (0x61-0x7A) but also `[` (0x5B), ```\``` (0x5C), `]` (0x5D), `^` (0x5E), `_` (0x5F), and `\`` (0x60).

Comment: @Gumbo Thanks, but this creates two groups in the result. But it's not a problem I can hack the result and extract the second group.

Comment: @4m1nh4j1 You could use a non-capturing group (`(?:…)`) instead.

Comment: @Jongware I used [A-z][A-Za-z0-9-_] because I am searching for a word not beginning with _. I think I can use [A-z]\w+ may be.

Comment: @4m1nh4j1: sure, that part is clear. But see Gumbo's explanation on my question.

Comment: @4m1nh4j1 You should double check whether you really want `[A-z]`, which is actually equivalent to `[A-Z[\\\]^_\`a-z]` and not to `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: @Gumbo ok, now I understand both of your comments.

Comment: @Jongware: `[A-z]` is never valid.  Even if you really wanted to match exactly that set of characters, it would be a mistake to use `[A-z]`, because everybody who sees the regex will assume you meant `[A-Za-z]`.  Even the author, revisiting the code after a month or so away, would probably forget why he did that and assume it was a typo.  Gumbo, would you please fix that?  My downvote finger's gettin' real itchy.